# occurrence to score

Tags: deep-learning

I get a frequency of words I would like to convert number_of_occuerence to a number between 0-10.

```
word     number_of_occurrence      score
and      200                       10
png      2                         1
where    50                        6 
news     120                       7
```

Comment: try apply with a lambda function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rate terms frequencies in a corpus, I suggest you to read this wikipedia article : [Term frequency–inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TF-IDF).

There are many ways to count the term frequency.
I understood want to rate it between 0 to 10.
I didn't get how you calculated you `score` values examples.
Anyway I suggest you an usual method: the log function.

[image]

```py
#count the occurrences of you terms
freq_table = {}
  words = tokenize(sentence)
  for word in words:
    word = word.lower()
    #stem the word if you can, using nltk
    if word in stopWords:#do you really want to count the occurrences of 'and'?
      continue

    if word in freq_table:
      freq_table[word] += 1
    else:
      freq_table[word] = 1
#log normalize the occurrences
for wordCount in freq_table.values():
  wordCount = 10*math.log(1+wordCount)
```

of course instead of log normalization you can use a normalization by the maximum.
[image]

```py
#ratio max normalize the occurrences
max = max(freq_table.values())
for wordCount in freq_table.values():
  wordCount = 10*wordCount/max
```

Or if you need a threshold effect,you can use a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) you could customize:
[image]

For more word processing check the [Natural Language Toolkit](https://www.nltk.org/). For a good term frequency count stematisation is good choice (stopwords are also useful)!

Answer (score -1):

Score is between 0-10. The maximum score is 10 for occurence 50, therefore anything higher than that should also has score 10. On the other hand, minimum score is 0, while the score is 1 for occurence 5, so assume anything lower than that has score 0.

Interpolation is based on your given condition only:

> If a word appear 50 times it should be closer to 10 and if a word
> appear 5 times it should be closer to 1.

```
df['score'] = df['number_of_occurrence'].apply(lambda x: x/5 if 5<=x<=50 else (0 if x< 5 else 10))
```

Output:
[image]